# How do I connect to multiple databases on the same SQL Server with sqlalchemy?

Tags: sql-server, sqlalchemy

I can specify the default database that the connection starts out in, but is it possible to switch databases, either when creating my engine, after creating it, or (preferably) when creating individual sessions?

Answer (score 0):

The DB is specified when you create the engine. Sounds like you would need to create another engine and then get a session off of that. If you really wanted and/or needed to you could use a function so you can pass in which db to connect to, and then have it return an engine and/or session.