# SQLAlchemy: Multiple databases (on the same server) in a single session?

Tags: sql-server, sqlalchemy

I'm running MS SQL Server and am trying to perform a `JOIN` between two tables located in different databases (on the same server).  If I connect to the server using pyodbc (without specifying a database), then the following raw SQL works fine.

```
SELECT * FROM DatabaseA.dbo.tableA tblA 
         INNER JOIN DatabaseB.dbo.tableB tblB 
         ON tblA.id = tblB.id
```

Unfortunately, I just can't seem to get the analog to work using SQLAlchemy.  I've seen this topic touched on in a few places:

- [Is there a way to perform a join across multiple sessions in sqlalchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859855/is-there-a-way-to-perform-a-join-across-multiple-sessions-in-sqlalchemy)
- [Cross database join in sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433592/cross-database-join-in-sqlalchem)
- [How do I connect to multiple databases on the same SQL Server with sqlalchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527746/how-do-i-connect-to-multiple-databases-on-the-same-sql-server-with-sqlalchemy)
- [How can I use multiple databases in the same request in Cherrypy and SQLAlchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634882/how-can-i-use-multiple-databases-in-the-same-request-in-cherrypy-and-sqlalchemy)

Most recommend to use different engines / sessions, but I crucially need to perform joins between the databases, so I don't think this approach will be helpful.  Another typical suggestion is to use the `schema` parameter, but this does not seem to work for me.  For example the following does not work.

```py
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://...')  #Does not specify database

metadataA = MetaData(bind=engine, schema='DatabaseA.dbo', reflect=True)
tableA = Table('tableA', metadataA, autoload=True)

metadataB = MetaData(bind=engine, schema='DatabaseB.dbo', reflect=True)
tableB = Table('tableB', metadataB, autoload=True)
```

I've also tried varients where `schema='DatabaseA'` and `schema='dbo'`.  In all cases SQLAlchemy throws a `NoSuchTableError` for both tables A and B.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you can create a synonym in one of the databases, you can keep your query local to that single database.

```
USE DatabaseB;
GO
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.DbA_TblA FOR DatabaseA.dbo.tableA;
GO
```

Your query then becomes:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.DbA_TblA tblA 
     INNER JOIN dbo.tableB tblB 
     ON tblA.id = tblB.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to run a test just like this here, reflecting from two remote databases, and it works fine.

1. Using a recent SQLAlchemy (0.8.3 recommended at least)?
2. turn on "echo='debug'" - what tables is it finding?
3. after the reflect all, what's present in metadataA.tables metadataB.tables?
4. is the casing here *exactly* what's on SQL server ?  (e.g. tableA).  Using a case sensitive name like that will cause it to be quoted.